# XNA Flash or Silverlight integration

Tags: c#, silverlight, flash, 3d, xna

I would like to play either a regular Flash movie or a Silverlight movie on top of a 3D scene rendered with XNA using C#. The background of the Flash/Silverlight object should be transparent, and be loaded dynamically by the 3D engine.

The idea is that third party developers and artists efficiently can add simple 2D animations as a layer on top of the 3D rendered scene to be played back in realtime.

Is this possible at all? And if so, any pointers?

Both Flash and Silverlight are what we have in mind now, but other technologies can also be considered. The idea is that the animated layer should be easy to make by artists, and easy to add dynamically, without the need to recompile the 3D engine.

It only needs to work on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, but I meant Flash/Silverlight. Flash/Silverlight!=video. It may have some interactive elements.

Anyway, I found a solution:

http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/

This allows me to render HTML on top of XNA rendered graphics, and it includes Flash support.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this won't work on Xbox 360 or WP7.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to get you up and running with playing the video in 2D.

[2D Video in XNA](http://web.archive.org/web/20100822053716/http://klucher.com/blog/video-support-in-xna-game-studio-3-1/)

My only thoughts on getting this to display on a 3D model, would be to create a `RenderTarget` and then display the video onto that.  An example can be seen [here](http://xnacommunity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20Cam&referringTitle=Ejemplos) where they are using a WebCam to display the video on a 3D model of a TV.

Comment: Each frame of the video you get a texture. Set that texture on the device. Then draw the model without allowing it to set its own texture (ModelMeshPart gives you vertex and index data to set directly on the graphics device, but there may be an easier way). That's how you draw video on a 3D model. No need for RenderTarget. Of course it sounds like sinsro wants a HUD-style render with transparent areas - and a video won't work for that.